# means of constants in R.java android

Tags: android, r.java-file

What is purpose of int constants from R class, where are that values used?
For example `public static final int number_list_item=0x7f04002b;`
When I use `findViewById()` I assign my view to that constant.
Is it some adress in memory? Could you explain, please.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hexadecimal value of the constant. 
Yes, it is a reserved memory space (**actually a pointer**) for the Android application.

Android R constants starts with the **0x7f0**...

**R.java** file is an auto-generated file by aapt (**Android Asset Packaging Tool**) that contains resource IDs for all the resources of res/ directory. when you create any resource within the classes or xml files; **aapt** creates a constant for internally accessing that resource.

Answer (score 1):

R.java file is an auto-generated file by Android Asset Packaging Tool that contains resource IDs for all the resources of res/ directory. when you create any component in the xml file, id for the corresponding component is automatically created in this file.

Answer (score 0):

It acts as bridge between String Resource in XML file and it's corresponding mapping in java.